# pojo object class is inserting duplicate value in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH99i.png)

I'm trying to insert data into my firebase but  whenever I click on upload button then instead of single value being added, another object is also added although I only define one pojo class. I have no idea where the next value is getting added by itself. Here is my screenshot of firebase database

Here is my class

```
package com.nepalpolice.filmyduniya.maincategory;
public class gender {
    public String bgenders;
    public gender( String bgenders) {
        this.bgenders=bgenders;
    }
    public gender(){}
    public String getBgender() { return bgenders; }
}
```

and my onClick listener is

```
 void postButtonClick() {
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
gender mygen = new gender(gend);
dbreference.child("location").child(loca).child(userId).setValue(mygen);
}
});
}
```

Comment: First of all make your `private String bgenders;`. Are you adding data to the database from other parts of your code?

Comment: yes I was but since I was getting the gender value twice, so i restricted myself to only this to  debug and still on defining only one item in class, still I"m getting two value in database.

Comment: So if you remove one duplicate from the database, when clicking on `b1` button you still get duplicates?